# insert received information into table on html

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, instagram-api

I am doing on a instagram api, and I get information from server including user profiles and two more kinds. I want to put the information in a table on html. Each row is related to a username(since I searched for username), and there are profiles and two more things on each row. I am a little confused about how to do that.

here is my code:

```
var searchUsers = function(query,count){

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    q: query,
    count: count,
    access_token: access_token,
  },
  url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search",
  success: function(data) {
    // placing the images on the page
    console.log(data);
    if (data.data.length>0){
        var resultShow = $("#users_result");
        for (var i in data.data){

            resultShow.append("<img src='" +      data.data[i].profile_picture + "'></img>");
            // var username = "https://www.instagram.com/"+ data.data[i].username;
            // console.log(username);
            resultShow.append("<a target='_blank' href = 'https://www.instagram.com/"+data.data[i].username+"'>user profile</a>");
            // var id = data.data[i].id;
            // console.log(id);
          $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + data.data[i].id + '/media/recent/',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {access_token: access_token},
          success: function(data2){
            console.log(data2);
          for(x in data2.data){
            // console.log(data2.data[x].link);
            resultShow.append("<a target='_blank' href = '"+data2.data[x].link+"'><img src='" + data2.data[x].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img></a>");  
              }

          },
          error: function(data2){
            console.log(data2);
          }
          });
    }
    } else {
        resultShow.html("Noting found!");
    }
    },
     error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}      
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change almost any value in a page using the innerHTML property.
Ex:`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";`
http://jsfiddle.net/blazeeboy/fNPvf/

To change the values inside a table, just assign an ID to it and change with your Javascript function.
In your case, I would suggest inserting any Javascript parameter between line 31 and 32.

```
 success: function(data2){
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var username = "https://www.instagram.com/"+ data.data[i].username;
    title.innerHTML = username;
            console.log(data2);
          for(x in data2.data){
            // console.log(data2.data[x].link);
            resultShow.append("<a target='_blank' href = '"+data2.data[x].link+"'><img src='" + data2.data[x].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img></a>");  
              }

          }
```

It will write the username into the table with id "title", if you need more than one table value, you'll need to make a array and use the for loop to insert an specific value into a specific table, tr, etc... id

```
success: function(data2){
    //tableids are the ids of each table row or column in the order you wanna write them
var tableids = ['0', '1', '2'];//starting at 0
var username = "https://www.instagram.com/"+ data.data[i].username;
var title = document.getElementById(tableids[i]);
title.innerHTML = username;
        console.log(data2);
      for(x in data2.data){
            // console.log(data2.data[x].link);
        resultShow.append("<a target='_blank' href = '"+data2.data[x].link+"'><img src='" + data2.data[x].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img></a>");  
          }

      }
```

Hope it was clear enough

Comment: Thanks! Since I want to make each column with different kinds , like      "<th><p class="text-center">Profile</p></th>
                <th><p class="text-center">User Account</p></th>
                <th><p class="text-center">Recent Media</p></th> "  and also I do ajax twice to get information, it is hard for me to insert each call to the end of a column. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I mean there is only tr for row in table, right? so how can I use for loops to insert a specific value at the end of a specific column? Or is there any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: You can change ANY value assigned by 'ID' with innerHTML (if it's html value), like text inputs, button input text, tr, tds, etc. This is using the for loop to cycle throught every thing and change accordingly with the array values.
You could also try calling a different function with the changes that you need to make.